# Create custom method for an object outside the class

Tags: java, oop, interface

In Android Studio you can write your own onClick function as shown below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do something
    }
});
```

I want to make something similar. I have an object that have an array inside, and by calling a function I want to access and modify that array.

My prototype :

```
object.useForProblems(new SomeInterface(){
    @Override
    start(){
        int[][] a = this.getArray();
        // do something with array
    }
});
```

I know that my prototype is not gonna work because the interface does not have an array, but I want to show my intention.

Comment: You need to pass the array to the `start()` method just like the view is passed to `onClick()`.

Comment: Good Idea! But what if the array is generated by a function inside the object? I have a graph class witch generate the array based on list of nodes.And let's say that the user want to modify the graph based on it's array. It's easier to modify the graph with the methods inside and generating the array again. I know that I can pass the graph object directly, but I want to know if it's possible to access methods and variables in that way.

Comment: Well, any code that wants to access data or methods needs to have a relation to what it wants to call. For static stuff it's quite easy (to get wrong :) ) because the only thing you need is access to the class. For instance methods and data your code needs access to that instance, i.e. some reference. Non-static inner classes have that reference implicitly while any other code would need some explicit handle on that instance (or the data itself) e.g. by passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an implementation that is aware of the array during construction (or later via custom setter method)

```
public class ArrayHolder implements SomeInterface {
    private final int[][] a;

    public ArrayHolder(int[][] a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    void start(){
        // do something with array
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Then

```
int[][] arrayHolder = ... // obtained from somewhere
ArrayHolder holder = new ArrayHolder(array);

object.useForProblems(arrayHolder);
```